# GetWindowText() doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

Initially I have to say that I know nothing about WinAPI. I'm learning from quite old tutorial, which seems to be a little bit outdated. I'm trying to make a dialog box where user would type in size of a next window. I've made it in Visual Studio using Resource Editor (or whatever it is called). I'm trying to retrieve data from Edit Controls, but GetWindowText doesn't work well.

So I made global LPTSTR named SizeX and SizeY (I know I could made them local and later pass them to a function that creates the second window, but I've got then problems with hInstance... nevermind).

```
BOOL CALLBACK SettingsProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            SetWindowTextA(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1), "20"); //I'm setting default input in case the user doesn't want to write anything
            SetWindowTextA(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2), "20");
        }
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case IDC_BUTTON1:
                {
                    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1), sizeX, GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1)) + 1);
                    if (sizeX == NULL)
                    break; //breaks every time
                    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2), sizeY, 10);
                    EndDialog(hwnd, IDC_BUTTON1);
                }
            break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default: return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
 }
```

I'm sure I have a lot of basic mistakes in this code, so please don't blame me :P
I have no idea how to make it work. The fantastic tutorial I use tells nothing about Edit Controls, it even has an information that it might be too old. Unfortunately that is the only WinAPI tutorial I've found in my language, if you know any good one in English I'd be glad.

Comment: How do you initialize sizeX? My guess is you don't (or zero), and the function call to GetWindowText cannot change the pointer. In which case this is a very basic C programming issue, not a winapi issue...

Comment: I just write LPTSTR sizeX... Is that a problem? I'm quite lost while coming to all those LPCWSTR, LPTSTR, LPCSTR, LPTSTR. To be honest I have no idea what they mean and what are differences.

Comment: "I just write LPTSTR sizeX in global scope" so `sizeX == 0` always true. you not allocate  `GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1)) + 1` for `sizeX`

Comment: OHHHH, I get it, LPTSTR is a pointer, not a char? Ok, nevermind, thanks :P

Comment: yes, this is pointer. you need allocate string buffer before call `GetWindowText`. and "problems with hInstance" - you need use `EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;` ->  `(HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase` in place `hInstance`

Comment: [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx). This won't teach you C++. It is expected, that you know C++ already. You don't appear to know C++ (or C even) well enough yet.

Comment: @RbMm: In addition to using the undocumented `__ImageBase` pseudo linker variable, the module handle for any calling code can be queried using the [GetModuleHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx) (by passing the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag, alongside the address of a local variable or function).

Comment: @IInspectable - "undocumented __ImageBase" - oh my god! i have no words

Comment: @IInspectable - even in some place on MSND - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/mt403328(v=vs.85).aspx "Windows Store apps should set this parameter to static_cast<HMODULE>(&__ImageBase)."

Comment: @RbMm: Why would you recommend writing code, that only compiles with Visual Studio, when a documented alternative exists, that compiles with **any** toolset? Unless you can provide official documentation for `__ImageBase`, it is an undocumented implementation detail of Visual Studio's linker. And if you *"have no words"*, there really is no need to express it with that much verbosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing that you should do is use directly `GetDlgItemInt` to retrieve `sizeX` and `sizeY` otherwise you should get text as a string then convert it into int:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
   {
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
        {

            BOOL bCheck = FALSE;
            sizeX = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, &bCheck, false);
            sizeY = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2, &bCheck, false);

            // or text then convert:
            int textLengthX = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
            int textLengthY = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);

            LPSTR lpTextX = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, textLengthX + 1);
            LPSTR lpTextY = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, textLengthY + 1);

            SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)textLengthX + 1, (LPARAM)lpTextX);
            SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)textLengthY + 1, (LPARAM)lpTextY);

            // now you have sizeX and sizeY as strings so convert them to int:
            int sizeX = atoi(lpTextX);
            int sizeY = atoi(lpTextY);

            GlobalFree(lpTextX);
            GlobalFree(lpTextY);
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```